# AOSP build failure using soong

Tags: android, android-source, android-soong

I am trying to build an Android Open Source  Project automotive image with a preinstalled system application using soong. The android system application is written in Kotlin.

Android.bp

```
android_app {
    name: "CarApp",

    srcs: ["src/**/*.kt", "src/**/*.java"],

    resource_dirs: [
     "res/"
    ],

    libs: [
     "telephony-common",
    ],
    certificate: "platform",
    privileged: true,
    platform_apis: true,
    optimize: {
        enabled: false,
    },
    dex_preopt: {
        enabled: false,
    },
    static_libs: [
     "android.car",
        "androidx.recyclerview_recyclerview",
        "androidx.recyclerview_recyclerview-selection",
        "androidx.preference_preference",
        "androidx-constraintlayout_constraintlayout",
        "android-support-design"
     ],

     
     plugins: ["dagger2-compiler-2.19"],

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.media.mycarapp">

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.type.automotive"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.car.permission.CAR_SPEED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.car.permission.CAR_POWERTRAIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.car.permission.CAR_ENERGY" />

    <application 
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
        <activity android:name=".SetupOptionsList"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".StatusActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".SetupActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

When I try to build using these files, I get

```
/out/soong/.intermediates/packages/apps/Car/CarApp/CarApp/android_common/manifest_fixer/AndroidManifest.xml:21:18-86 Error:
    Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory) from AndroidManifest.xml:21:18-86
    is also present at AndroidManifest.xml:21:18-91 value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:12:5-23:19 to override.
```

After adding **'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"** to AndroidManifest.xml, I get an unbound **prefix error** when the application is being built. The error is as below.

```
out/soong/host/linux-x86/bin/manifest_fixer --minSdkVersion 30 --targetSdkVersion 30 --raise-min-sdk-version --extract-native-libs=true --uses-non-sdk-api packages/apps/Car/JulioApp/AndroidManifest.xml o
ut/soong/.intermediates/packages/apps/Car/CarApp/CarApp/android_common/manifest_fixer/AndroidManifest.xml
error: unbound prefix: line 13, column 4
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Never use uncommon abbreviations. What is AOSP? `Is it Android Open Source  Project`?

Comment: Yes, it is. updated

Comment: AOSP is a very common abbreviation.

Answer (score 0):

@Pie - AOSP is definitely in common domain.

If you are specifically trying to build this code using soong, then this answer is not for you. But below I describe an alternative to doing just that.

You don't need to build kotlin code in AOSP. Build the APK in Android Studio, sign with system certificate, and then create a folder under maybe `~/AOSP/packages/apps/<your-app>` and add two files under there. You'll find exact information on many different SO questions on how to add an APK to AOSP. So you'll create your `Android.mk` file and place that apk file there. In your `mk` file, you'll mention that it is pre-signed.

Next, you'll add this package name in your `device.mk` as `PRODUCT_PACKAGES += <PACKAGE_NAME>`. This is will include that app as a system application on the device. No other steps will be required, and you'll find this app under `/system/priv-app` as well.

Depending on the situation, you may also need `priv-app-permissions.xml` and include that like so:

```
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/root/privapp-permissions-<DEVICE>.xml:system/etc/permissions/privapp-permissions-<DEVICE>.xml
```

Adding Apps to AOSP Build (Cannot link, but search on SO)

- How do I add an application in AOSP?
- How can I add a 3rd-party library to an Android AOSP build?
- Error when adding external JAR to Android AOSP build
- How to solve Error: This attribute must be localized. (at 'text' with value 'TOP_LEFT')
- X (java:sdk) should not link to Y (java:platform)
- Adding a jar file from libs/ to Android.mk
- Add one android project as a library in AOSP App
- Default Launcher: How do I set the default launcher in an AOSP build?
- Add native service to aosp
- Building a particular module in the android source code
- Dependencies between 2 Android.mk files